# The model deletion in Ruby on Rails (Rspec) is not deleting the item ontime, just later (Database: Mongo with Replica Sets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rspec, automated-tests, mongoid

First, I'm using `Mongo` with the read preference of the replica sets configured as `secondary`, which can cause the [asynchronous replication behavior](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/replication/#asynchronous-replication)

I have the following code in my automated tests:

```rb
1.  context 'success' doz
2.    before do
3.      @role = Role.create!(name: 'admin')
4.
5.      @count_before = Role.count
6.      @role.destroy!
7.      @count_after1 = Role.count # => 1
8.      @count_after2 = Role.count # => 0
9.      @count_after3 = Role.count # => 0
10.     @count_after4 = Role.count # => 0
11.     @count_after5 = Role.count # => 0
12.     @count_after6 = Role.count # => 0
13.   end
14
15.   it 'should delete properly' do
16.     expect(@count_after1).to be_eql(@count_before - 1)
17.   end
18. end
```

However, somehow

1. the `@cound_after1` (**line 7**) has the `1` value (the outdated one, because the Role item was deleted in **line 6**;
2. the `@count_after2` (**line 8**) has the `0` value (the correct one).

More than that, this behavior happens intermittently. Sometimes it works and all `@count_after`s has the `0` value, sometimes it doesn't and `@count_after1` is have the `1` value.

Changing the `read_preference` of the `mongoid.yml` file from `secondary` to `primary` is not a valid solution, because we need to reproduce the production environment on the test suite properly.

How can we fix that?

I tried to debug the code and sadly I still didn't discover a possible solution to this issue. It looks like this is due to an [asynchronous issue, because the Role item is deleted afterwards](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/read-preference/#behavior). It is also good to note that this issue happens intermittently: Sometimes the test pass and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: What's the bug or problem here? This behavior is expected. Per [the docs for `secondary` read preference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/read-preference/#mongodb-readmode-secondary): "_Read operations using the `secondary` mode may return stale data._" If stale data is unacceptable and you must read from `SECONDARY` members, then you will need to use an elevated [read concern](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/read-concern/)

Comment: The problem relies on the fact that there are multiple automated tests that will check for database-related operations, such as **read**, **create**, **update** or **delete**. However, since the database will return stale data, all of the tests that checks for database operations will intermittently fail.

Comment: Then either your tests are incorrectly expecting behavior that is not guaranteed (synchronous replication) or the way that the app/tests write and/or read the data is not appropriate based on your business requirements. The database itself is behaving as designed and as configured by your app

Comment: I need to have a replica configured to perform a transaction rollback in development code. However, I also need to test if the **read**, **create**, **update** and **delete** of items in the test suite are creating, updating, deleting or reading items as expected. I know the database is "behaving as I designed", but it is clearly not attending my pre-requisites and that's why I opened this issue here. It seems like your intention is just to feel right instead of helping me.

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is not a bug.

From the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/read-preference/#behavior) you linked:

> All read preference modes except primary may return stale data because secondaries replicate operations from the primary in an asynchronous process.   Ensure that your application can tolerate stale data if you choose to use a non-primary mode.

All data is written to the primary.  It then takes non-zero time to replicate that data to the secondary nodes.

If you need to ensure all nodes in the replica set have processed the write, you could use the write concern "w:all" instead of the default "w:1".

Comment: And **how** and **where** can I use the concern `"w:all"` instead of the default `"w:1"`? An example would be good to clarify that solution. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with this answer but with the additional caveat that adjusting write concern is only helpful for the single threaded test/workflow. Other concurrent readers can still see stale data when reading from SECONDARY members with this approach unless they use an elevated (non-default) read concern

Comment: non-default read concern won't help much.  The key here is the old data isn't stale until the write is completed. With w:all, the write operation won't return until all of the nodes have the data